# Why total swaps and page faults/reclaims is empty in ps?

Tags: osx, ps, swap, virtual-memory

I'm running the following command:

```
sudo ps -axo nswap,majflt,minflt,command | sort -nr | head
```

which suppose to print total swaps in/out, total page faults and reclaims.

But for given >400 processes, prints nothing. I've uptime of 18 days, so I think it should print something in these columns, but only dashes (`-`). Any ideas why it's not?

Comment: I do not know what is the OSX equivalent of `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` but I found [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8461/is-there-a-way-to-reduce-the-swappiness-of-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard).  What are the values in your `sysctl` config?

Comment: Pasted [here](https://gist.github.com/kenorb/149dd75b891b5d38412dca73273dc643).

Comment: Yes its very weird, top shows non-empty "FAULTS" column which seems legit.